# Harry Potter fanfic in which Harry becomes an infant with the mind of an adult

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a *Harry Potter* fan-fiction that I read a while ago. I can't remember the name and when I try and search up the concepts I still can't find it.
Here are some of the things I remember about it:

- Harry ends up back as an infant at some point after the books but he still has the mind of an adult.
- When he goes to his first day of school, he reads a highly advanced book in class, to which the teacher asks him to read a passage of, thinking he'll just make something up. When he doesn't, the teacher goes to the principal and asks for Harry to be moved up a grade or two.
- He manages to graduate college and get a job teaching at a university before his Hogwarts letter comes.
- He grades homework at Hogwarts

Comment: The fics at https://www.fanfiction.net/community/Deaged-Harry/63453/ might help.

Comment: Thanks FuzzyBoots, but it wasn't on there.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Is it called "[The White Lord](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5868768/1/The-White-Lord)"?

> Harry Potter saved the world, but was betrayd. He learns about his place in the universe and goes back in time to change everything HP/LV

From chapter 3:

> The next day he showed up at the classroom, prim and proper in a suit, a tie and pressed pants. He looked over the students, making his gaze linger a bit at Hadrian, who again sat with a book reading instead of looking up at the teacher, before he cleared his throat.
>
> "I am Mr. Berns and I am taking over this class today while Ms. Temp is teaching another class. I want you all to place away all things on your desks because we are going to have reading aloud this class."
>
> Hadrian just continued to read from his book, once again a book on rhetoric. Suddenly the teacher, Mr. Berns stood beside his desk smiling at him. "Young man, it seems to me like you would like to begin the reading session? Please read out loud from that book you have."
>
> Hadrian did not look up at him, just shrugged his shoulders and mumbled; "If you insist, sir."

Comment: Can you provide details on how this matches?

Comment: I've added a link to a likely fanfic, and its summary, but given all I had was a title, I might have gotten the wrong one.

Comment: This is the one I was talking about, the part that happened on the first day of school that you described happens on chapter 3

Comment: :) In that case, you can add a quote by using an Angle bracket as per Markup. "> Harry wandered into the classroom and reflected that Professor McGonnagle was dressed very oddly." will be rendered in an offset way to indicate it's a quote. When you [edit] the post, you'll see that's how I quoted the summary. If you have trouble highlighting text on FF.net, you can either go into the mobile mode, or use the Inspect console ("Ctrl+Shift+I") to get the text.